# Unexpected behavior with list.append

Tags: python, list, append, ipython

I was working with my interpreter to figure out the behavior of the Python `append()` method and found:

```
In [335]: b = [].append(1)

In [336]: b

In [337]: 

In [337]: b = [].append('1')

In [338]: b
```

Which puzzles me because I thought that whenever we call `append()` on a list, we add new objects to its end, so shouldn't calling `append()` on an empty list (as what I did above) give me the the same result that I could achieve with:

```
In [339]: b=[] 

In [340]: b.append(1)

In [341]: b
Out[341]: [1]
```

I might have a misconception here, so please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which puzzles me because I thought that whenever we call `append()` on a
>   list, we add new objects to its end

That is correct.  But what you are forgetting is that `append()` (like most methods which mutate objects) always returns `None` in Python because it operates in-place.  So, doing this:

```
b = [].append(1)
```

is the same as:

```
b = None
```

`1` is technically added to the list `[]`, but there is no way to access this list after the call to `append()` since `b` is assigned to the return value of the method call.

The second example works fine simply because you are not reassigning `b` and thereby losing the reference to the list object.

Comment: Oh right. Hmmm and is there any reason why it is good for `apppend()` to return a `None`? Is it because, like in the second example, when I did `b.append()`, if `append()` did not return a `None`, then it would modify the type of `b` and change its value? Because right now it seems to me that if `append()` always returns a `None` then calling `append()` on `b` should also cause the value of `b` to change to `None` even in the second example. What's my misconception here?

Comment: I believe the rationale is that it enforces simplicity and explicitness. You have to do one thing at a time, and avoid humongous spaghetti statements with chains of side effects.

Comment: @AKKO - Well, you'd have to ask the Python core-devs for the *exact* reason why `append()` returns `None`.  It is really just a design decision.  I would guess that it is so that you cannot bury the call inside another line.  Since `append()` mutates the list, it should be on its own line to call attention to it.  In fact, almost all of the methods which mutate an object in Python follow this convention and return `None`.

Comment: Thanks @iCodez @tripleee for your responses. I guess this clarifies everythin. And I sort of figured out the answer to my own question that I raised in the comment above : _then calling append() on b should also cause the value of b to change to None_  While `b` will always be a list, doing something like `b.append(1)` itself will give my a `NoneType` when I do `type(b.append(1))`, the type of `b` itself is not modified. However, say if I were to assign a variable to the expression `a = b.append(1)`, then the type of `a` would be `NoneType`. I guess its an issue of R-values and L-values.

Answer (score 2):

`append` is a method that doesn't return anything. So calling `ls.append(1)` will append `1` to the end of `ls`, but `ls.append(1)` has no actual value. So setting `b = [].append('1')` sets `b` to `None`.